# Iterating item in a loop

Tags: c#, java, javascript, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have a `List<int>` with the values like `60,45,45,45,45,30,60,60,15` people

Also i have two slots. 1st slot is capable to occupy `180` people

Problem is I need to loop `List<int>` to fill Slot1 with 180 people

```
var slotCount=0;
foreach(int i in list)
{
  slot[slotCount]=i;
  slotCount++;
  //Here till 60+45+45=150 its ok.
  //But if i add next item 45, I cross my slot limit(195). 
  //So i need to pick 30 from list, so it will 180 
}
```

**Once this slot is filled with 180, I need to create another slot and add the remaining.**

I am struggling with this logic. Any algorithm/approach welcome!

**Note:**

> 1st slot is always 180 2nd slot can be 0-180 or maximum 240
>
> If the list has more items we schedule it for next day, by creating
>   slot1 & slot 2 again for Day 2

---

This is what i tried but failed :(

```
class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
class Slot
{
    public int MaxSize { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public int OccupiedSize
    {
        get
        {
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Group g in Groups)
            {
                count += g.Count;
            }
            return count;
        }
    }
}
class Schedule
{
    public Slot MorningSlot { get; set; }
    public Slot EveningSlot { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>{new Group{Count=60},
            new Group{Count=45},new Group{Count=45},new Group{Count=45},
            new Group{Count=45}, new Group{Count=30},new Group{Count=60},
            new Group{Count=60},new Group{Count=15}
        };

        int eventsCount = groups.Count;

        List<Schedule> shedules = new List<Schedule>();

        while (eventsCount > 0)
        {

            Schedule sched = new Schedule();
            sched.MorningSlot = new Slot();
            sched.MorningSlot.MaxSize = 180;

            sched.EveningSlot = new Slot();
            sched.EveningSlot.MaxSize = 240;

            sched.MorningSlot.Groups = new List<Group>();
            sched.EveningSlot.Groups = new List<Group>();

            foreach (Group g in groups.ToList())
            {

                if (sched.MorningSlot.OccupiedSize + g.Count 
                    <= sched.MorningSlot.MaxSize)
                {
                    sched.MorningSlot.Groups.Add(g);
                    groups.Remove(g);
                    eventsCount--;
                }
                else if (sched.EveningSlot.OccupiedSize + g.Count 
                   <= sched.EveningSlot.MaxSize)
                {
                    sched.EveningSlot.Groups.Add(g);
                    groups.Remove(g);
                    eventsCount--;
                }
            }

            shedules.Add(sched);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: More suitable for [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Comment: by `slot`, you mean you have two `List<int>` to fill with at maximum of 180 elements each?

Comment: Is it exactly 180 or can it be less than that?

Comment: @JW Only 1st slot will fill 180. Other slot will occupy maximum 240 or remaining items in a `List<int>`, it can be 0-180

Comment: Updated my question with `Note`

Comment: This question was asked the other day, in a slightly different way...

Comment: Have you thought about , sorting it? What happens with the numbers, that are already in slots? Can you reuse them?

Comment: This is the famous "subset sum" problem; there is no known fast solution if the set of numbers is large and it is conjectured that there is no fast solution. This is an extremely well-studied problem; you should have no difficulty in finding papers on how to solve it for small cases.

Comment: @IamStalker it is not a problem. I can reuse. Its just a group of people to fit in a slot. A & B group both can be a number of 45 and accommodate in a room

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for giving me a hint `subset sum`. started googling to understand :)

Comment: Maybe you could mention that in your duplicate question here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11059/filling-slot-based-on-limit

Comment: @JeremyThompson, updated codegolf

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LINQ` to calculate the current sum of each `List`.

```
int _maxSlotA = 180;
int _maxSlotB = 240;

List<int> _slotA = new List<int>();
List<int> _slotB = new List<int>();

foreach(int i in list)
{
    if (_slotA.Sum() < _maxSlotA)
    {
        _slotA.Add(i);
    }
    elseif (_slotB.Sum() < _maxSlotB)
    {
        _slotB.Add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is good as it can be read as "pseudo code" which will suit the OP having listed multiple languages.

Comment: should `_slotA.Count` really be `_slotA.Sum`? Unless you meant `Count` as being the summation.

Comment: Hey what is LINQ? I googled and came up with Language query but this doesnt seem to be it. And why the _ before variable names?

Comment: @karmanaut [LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b), and for your second question, it's my own naming convention so i can easily know the scope of the variable whther it is public, private, or only in the method level `:)`

Comment: Have you shared this naming convention anywhere else? Is it a pseudo standard or something?

Comment: In your code `_slotA.Count` is just taking count rather than checking sum of items added in it. Check with sum and also check else if part too. It gives strange result :)

Comment: see my updated answer, this time it uses `SUM()` which is an extension method.

Comment: `170,20,50,25` consider the above data, now your code will display like this: _slotA ---> 170,20 _slotB ---> 50,25. Now see The sum of _SlotA has exceeded 180. I wonder, is this right.? or did i answer this question, with out understanding it fully.? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Input Sample I:** xPeople -- 60,45,45,45,45,30,60,60,15

```
//OutPut
Slot I: [60, 45, 45, 30]
Slot II: [45, 45, 60, 60]
Un-Allocated:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15]
```

**Input Sample II:** xPeople -- 75,45,45,45,45,30,60,60,15

```
//OutPut
Slot I: [75, 45, 45, 15]
Slot II: [45, 45, 30, 60, 60]
Un-Allocated:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Input Sample III:** xPeople -- 128,11,8,69,6,76,41,54,5,4,2,3,2,100

```
//OutPut
Slot I: [128, 11, 8, 33]
Slot II: [36, 6, 76, 41, 54, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 11]
Un-Allocated:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89]
```

This code was Tested With `IDE`, I possibly tested this in many cases, if you find any problem with this, just make a comment in my post.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        ArrayList<Integer> xPeople=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        xPeople.add(60); xPeople.add(45); xPeople.add(45);
        xPeople.add(45); xPeople.add(45); xPeople.add(30);
        xPeople.add(60); xPeople.add(60); xPeople.add(15);

        ArrayList<Integer> xSlotOne=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> xSlotTwo=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int xSlotOneCnt=0;
        int xSlotTwoCnt=0;

        for(int i=0; i<xPeople.size();i++) 
        {

            if(xSlotOneCnt<180)
            {
                if (xSlotOneCnt + xPeople.get(i) >180)
                {
                    if(xPeople.indexOf(180 - xSlotOneCnt) != -1)
                    {
                        xSlotOne.add(xPeople.get(xPeople.indexOf(180 - xSlotOneCnt)));
                        xPeople.set(xPeople.indexOf(180 - xSlotOneCnt),0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xSlotOne.add(180 - xSlotOneCnt);
                        xPeople.set(i,  xPeople.get(i) - (180 - xSlotOneCnt));
                    }

                    xSlotOneCnt += 180 - xSlotOneCnt;
                }
                else
                {
                    xSlotOne.add(xPeople.get(i));
                    xSlotOneCnt += xPeople.get(i);

                    xPeople.set(i, 0);
                }
            }

                          //The code inside this if statement is as same the
                          //code which is inside the above If statement[if(xSlotOneCnt<180)]
                          //So please use a function in this case to avoid code repetetion.

            if(xSlotTwoCnt < 240 && xPeople.get(i) > 0)
            {

                                if (xSlotTwoCnt + xPeople.get(i) >240)
                {
                    if(xPeople.indexOf(240 - xSlotTwoCnt) != -1)
                    {
                        xSlotTwo.add(xPeople.get(xPeople.indexOf(240 - xSlotTwoCnt)));
                        xPeople.set(xPeople.indexOf(240 - xSlotTwoCnt),0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xSlotTwo.add(240 - xSlotTwoCnt);
                        xPeople.set(i,  xPeople.get(i) - (240 - xSlotTwoCnt));
                    }

                    xSlotTwoCnt += 240 - xSlotTwoCnt;
                }
                else
                {
                    xSlotTwo.add(xPeople.get(i));
                    xSlotTwoCnt += xPeople.get(i);
                    xPeople.set(i, 0);
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Slot I: " + xSlotOne);
        System.out.println("Slot II: " + xSlotTwo);
        System.out.println("Un-Allocated:" + xPeople);

    }

}
```

Comment: Looks nice. But just a small update, I am dealing with `List<Group>` and `Group class` has `Count` type of int. Also i am not able to understand `xPeople.indexOf(180 - xSlotOneCnt) != -1` statement

Comment: you can't able to understand indexOf() .?

Comment: Added my code as answer below. How do i check indexOf for a object?